# Sum and Average Array of Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sum array of array and get average at the same time. The original data is in the form of `JSON`. I have to parse my data to array of array in order to render the graph. The graph does not accept array of hash.

I first convert the `output` to JSON using the definition below.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@output.first(10).to_json)
```

And the result of the above action is shown below.

```
output = 
[{"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 2, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 4, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 6, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 8, ... },
 {"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 2, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 4, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 6, ... }, 
 {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 10, ... }, 
]
```

Then I retrieved the `job` and `pay` by converting to array of array.

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(output.to_json).each { |h| 
  a << [h['job'], h['pay']]
}
```

The result of the above operation is as below.

```
a = [["a", 2], ["a", 4], ["a", 6], ["a", 8],
     ["b", 2], ["b", 4], ["b", 6], ["b", 10]]
```

The code below will give me the sum of each element in the form of array of array.

```
a.inject({}) { |h,(job, data)| h[job] ||= 0; h[job] += data; h }.to_a
```

And the result is as below

```
[["a", 20], ["b", 22]]
```

However, I am trying to get the average of the array. The expected output is as below.

```
[["a", 5], ["b", 5.5]]
```

I can count how many elements in an array and divide the `sum` array by the `count` array. I was wondering if there is an easier and more efficient way to get the average.

Comment: Can you create a hash of the format `{a: [2, 4, 6, 8], b: [2, 4, 6, 20]}`, get the average (more easily) and then convert that into the array of arrays?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts Yeah, that's what I was thinking at first and I saw many answered question with array of hash. But I have to filter out the keys that I want first. There is about 10 keys but I only need two.

Comment: Can you show a bit of how you are doing the filtering?

Comment: @SaraTibbetts updated. I will use any method that is most efficient as I am trying to do it on 80K rows of data.

Comment: Wow you literally just changed the whole question and invalidated all the answers proposed. Why would you do this?

Comment: @engineersmnky The answer is still unchanged. I am trying to get array of array still, with average. Edit: Wait, I changed the values! I will change back the values now!

Comment: How would you like to get the average at the same time as summing. If you were going to do this by hand per se, understanding what an average is, you know that you would have to count the elements and then add them up and divide by the count. This is a 3 step process count, add, divide. You cannot determine the average of anything until you know the sum and the count.

Comment: @engineersmnky As mentioned in the last sentence, I can get an array of `sum` and another array of `count`. Then I divide the `sum` my `count` (and store in another array). But it might not be efficient as I am dealing with huge rows of data.

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng I've updated my answer to fit your problem update.

Comment: When you give an example, please make it a valid Ruby object. Here you are forcing everyone who answers to strip out the `...`'s in `output`. You seem to have been in a rush to select an answer. How many answers had been posted when you did so? 1? 2? There are now 5. My observation has nothing to do with your choice; in your shoes I may have selected it as well, but not before time was allowed for others to post answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = [
  {"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 2 }, 
  {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 4 }, 
  {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 6 }, 
  {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 8 },
  {"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 2 }, 
  {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 4 }, 
  {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 6 }, 
  {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 10 }, 
]

output.group_by { |obj| obj['job'] }.map do |key, list|
  [key, list.map { |obj| obj['pay'] }.reduce(:+) / list.size.to_f]
end
```

The `group_by` method will transform your list into a hash with the following structure:

```
{"a"=>[{"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"a", "pay"=>2}, ...], "b"=>[{"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"b", ...]}
```

After that, for each pair of that hash, we want to calculate the mean of its `'pay'` values, and return a pair `[key, mean]`. We use a map for that, returning a pair with:

1. They key itself (`"a"` or `"b"`).
2. The mean of the values. Note that the values list has the form of a list of hashes. To retrieve the values, we need to extract the last element of each pair; that's what `list.map { |obj| obj['pay'] }` is used for. Finally, calculate the mean by suming all elements with `.reduce(:+)` and dividing them by the list size as a float.

Not the most efficient solution, but it's practical.

---

Comparing the answer with @EricDuminil's, here's a benchmark with a list of size `8.000.000`:

```
def Wikiti(output)
  output.group_by { |obj| obj['job'] }.map do |key, list|
    [key, list.map { |obj| obj['pay'] }.reduce(:+) / list.size.to_f]
  end
end

def EricDuminil(output)
  count_and_sum = output.each_with_object(Hash.new([0, 0])) do |hash, mem|
    job = hash['job']
    count, sum = mem[job]
    mem[job] = count + 1, sum + hash['pay']
  end
  result = count_and_sum.map do |job, (count, sum)|
    [job, sum / count.to_f]
  end
end

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('Wikiti') { Wikiti(output) }
  x.report('EricDuminil') { EricDuminil(output) }
end

user         system      total        real
Wikiti       4.100000    0.020000     4.120000 (  4.130373)
EricDuminil  4.250000    0.000000     4.250000 (  4.272685)
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Loaded with 3000 lines of data, the graph is generated within 1-2 seconds (localhost). Thank you!

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng: 3000 lines of data is nowhere near "huge". Any method would do in this case.

Comment: @EricDuminil I actually have close to 400K rows, I only tested with 3K. I am trying out each method to see which one is faster.

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng you know there are benchmarking tools for that right?

Comment: @engineersmnky use `require 'benchmark'`? I will go through each of the answers and chose the best answer again.

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng: fruity gem is reliable, easy to use and has nice output for benchmarking.

Comment: I prefer the `fruity` gem but the built in benchmark (e.g. `require 'benchmark'`) works well too. @EricDuminil beat me to it as well

Comment: @MelvinCh'ng I've added a benchmark with the answers I considered correct.

Comment: @Wikiti where's the love. No benchmark for me? (I'd run them myself but I'm away from my machine) and need minor modifications to return the Array version

Comment: @engineersmnky Once you've updated your solution to accept the question input, and produce the desired output, I'll be pleased to add it to the benchmark. Feel free to notify me :)

Comment: I've tried a benchmark with all the answers. They all have similar performances. So it makes sense to pick the clearest and most concise answer, which is this one IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil I am actually showing yours is a bit faster by ~10% (Mine is the slowest to get to the desired output) :P

Comment: @engineersmnky I've noticed it too, but only with some input. 10% aren't really worth the extra complexity IMHO. It makes sense that your method is slower, you do provide a bit more information than the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

This method should be reasonably efficient. It creates a temporary hash with job name as key and `[count, sum]` as value:

```
output = [{ 'name' => 'aaa', 'job' => 'a', 'pay' => 2 },
          { 'name' => 'zzz', 'job' => 'a', 'pay' => 4 },
          { 'name' => 'xxx', 'job' => 'a', 'pay' => 6 },
          { 'name' => 'yyy', 'job' => 'a', 'pay' => 8 },
          { 'name' => 'aaa', 'job' => 'b', 'pay' => 2 },
          { 'name' => 'zzz', 'job' => 'b', 'pay' => 4 },
          { 'name' => 'xxx', 'job' => 'b', 'pay' => 6 },
          { 'name' => 'yyy', 'job' => 'b', 'pay' => 10 }]

count_and_sum = output.each_with_object(Hash.new([0, 0])) do |hash, mem|
  job = hash['job']
  count, sum = mem[job]
  mem[job] = count + 1, sum + hash['pay']
end
#=> {"a"=>[4, 20], "b"=>[4, 22]}

result = count_and_sum.map do |job, (count, sum)|
  [job, sum / count.to_f]
end
#=> [["a", 5.0], ["b", 5.5]]
```

It requires 2 passes, but the created objects aren't big. In comparison, calling `group_by` on a huge array of hashes isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (Single pass iterative average calculation)

```
accumulator = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(0)}
a.each_with_object(accumulator) do |(k,v),obj|
   obj[k][:count] += 1
   obj[k][:sum] += v
   obj[k][:average] = (obj[k][:sum] / obj[k][:count].to_f)
end
#=> {"a"=>{:count=>4, :sum=>20, :average=>5.0}, 
#     "b"=>{:count=>4, :sum=>22, :average=>5.5}}
```

Obviously average is just recalculated on every iteration but since you asked for them at the same time this is probably as close as you are going to get.

Using your "output" instead looks like

```
output.each_with_object(accumulator) do |h,obj|
   key = h['job']
   obj[key][:count] += 1
   obj[key][:sum] += h['pay']
   obj[key][:average] = (obj[key][:sum] / obj[key][:count].to_f)
end

#=> {"a"=>{:count=>4, :sum=>20, :average=>5.0}, 
#     "b"=>{:count=>4, :sum=>22, :average=>5.5}}
```

Comment: Nice. `Hash.new(0)` should be enough for the inner hash of your accumulator.

Comment: @EricDuminil fair and updated I usually use block form but since the `Integer` is immutable that makes sense. I have fallen into that stupid trap using an empty `String` or `Hash` one to many times that block form is just instinctual at this point

Answer (score 0):

as Sara Tibbetts comment suggests, my first step would be to convert it like this

```
new_a = a.reduce({}){ |memo, item| memo[item[0]] ||= []; memo[item[0]] << item[1]; memo}
```

which puts it in this format

```
{a: [2, 4, 6, 8], b: [2, 4, 6, 20]}
```

you can then use `slice` to filter the keys you want

```
new_a.slice!(key1, key2, ...)
```

Then do another pass through to do get the final format

```
new_a.reduce([]) do |memo, (k,v)|
  avg = v.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / v.size
  memo << [k,avg]
  memo
end
```

Comment: Why do you mix `reduce` and `inject`? If you always return `memo` at the end of your `reduce`, it means you need `each_with_object`.

Answer (score 0):

I elected to use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with the object being an array of two hashes, the first to compute totals, the second to count the number of numbers that are totalled. Each hash is defined `Hash.new(0)`, zero being the *default value*. See [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) for a fuller explanation, In short, if a hash defined `h = Hash.new(0)` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns `0`. (`h` is not modified.) `h[k] += 1` expands to `h[k] = h[k] + 1`. If `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right of the equality returns `0`.<sup>1</sup>

```
output =
[{"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 2},
 {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 4},
 {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 6},
 {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"a", "pay"=> 8},
 {"name"=>"aaa", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 2},
 {"name"=>"zzz", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 4},
 {"name"=>"xxx", "job"=>"b", "pay"=> 6},
 {"name"=>"yyy", "job"=>"b", "pay"=>10}
]

htot, hnbr = output.each_with_object([Hash.new(0), Hash.new(0)]) do |f,(g,h)|
  s = f["job"]
  g[s] += f["pay"]
  h[s] += 1
end
htot.merge(hnbr) { |k,o,n| o.to_f/n }.to_a
  #=> [["a", 5.0], ["b", 5.5]]
```

If `.to_a` at the end is dropped the the hash `{"a"=>5.0, "b"=>5.5}` is returned. The OP might find that more useful than the array.

I've used the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

Note that `htot={"a"=>20, "b"=>22}` and `hnbr=>{"a"=>4, "b"=>4}`.

<sup>1 If the reader is wondering why `h[k]` on the left of `=` doesn't return zero as well, it's a different method: `Hash#[]=` versus `Hash#[]`</sup>